# Click an action button and save ggplot as pdf

Tags: pdf, ggplot2, shiny, download, save

I am attempting to download/save a dynamically output ggplot as a pdf after a downloadButton is pushed.

I have attempted various ways to do this from multiple sources online and have been unsuccessful each time. I have attached the pertinent code in hopes that someone could assist me in creating the appropriate function "downloadPlot".

```
ui <- ......
      .
      .
downloadButton('downloadPlot','Download Image'),
      .
      .
server <- function(input,output,session){
      .                                           
      .
# DP Box Plots 
  output$one <- renderPlot({
    if(input$layer == "State Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$ES, "Please select a state to access the box plots."))
      }
    else if(input$layer == "Niche Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$niche, "Please select a niche to access the box plot.")
      )
    }
    else if(input$layer == "State/Niche Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$SoN, "Please select a state. ")
      )
      validate(
        need(input$NoS, "Please select a niche. ")
      )
    }
    else if(input$layer == "New/Renewal Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$NR, "Please select new or renewal to view box plots.")
      )
    }

    ggplot(Dataset(), aes(x= reorder(Niche_Groups, 
Discretionary_Price_Relativity, FUN = median), y = 
Discretionary_Price_Relativity)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + 
ggtitle(paste("Discretionary Pricing - ",titlename())) + theme(plot.title = 
element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       ylab("Ratio to Technical") + xlab("Niche Groups")
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
server <- function(input,output,session){
  .                                           
  .

  theplot <- reactive({
    if(input$layer == "State Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$ES, "Please select a state to access the box plots."))
    }
    else if(input$layer == "Niche Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$niche, "Please select a niche to access the box plot.")
      )
    }
    else if(input$layer == "State/Niche Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$SoN, "Please select a state. ")
      )
      validate(
        need(input$NoS, "Please select a niche. ")
      )
    }
    else if(input$layer == "New/Renewal Specific"){
      validate(
        need(input$NR, "Please select new or renewal to view box plots.")
      )
    }

    ggplot(Dataset(), aes(x= reorder(Niche_Groups, 
                                     Discretionary_Price_Relativity, FUN = median), y = 
                            Discretionary_Price_Relativity)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + 
      ggtitle(paste("Discretionary Pricing - ",titlename())) + theme(plot.title = 
                                                                       element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      ylab("Ratio to Technical") + xlab("Niche Groups")    
  })

  output$one <- renderPlot({
    theplot()
  })

  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "theplot.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      ggsave(file, theplot())
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! While I am still working on it, is there any way to control the ratio of how it appears within the pdf from the same downloadHandler function?

Comment: @Monty-PYTHON See `?ggsave`. You can give a width and a height.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using "scale = " in addition to altering the height. Thank you.